# onTouch: detect ACTION_UP without blocking other touch events

Tags: android, android-gesture, android-touch-event

I have a custom view which acts as a button. I am drawing all the canvas myself. Now I'm making an outline when `ACTION_DOWN` and remove it after `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL`.

```
@Override
public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    switch (event.getAction()) {
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
            Log.e("test", "ACTION_DOWN");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
            Log.e("test", "ACTION_UP");
            break;
        case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
            Log.e("test", "ACTION_CANCEL");
            break;
    }

    return true;
}
```

This can work for me, except now it is blocking another gesture behind this view which is detecting `ACTION_MOVE` (scroll left).

If I return false, then it is working fine but now `ACTION_UP` is not called.

I want to call `ACTION_UP` if finger is lifted, but pass events down otherwise.

Comment: You might to use [GestureDetector](https://developer.android.com/training/gestures/scroll)

Comment: @DrumRobot how do you mean. Note I cannot touch other view. only this one

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried overriding `dispatchTouchEvent`?

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.html#dispatchTouchEvent(android.view.MotionEvent)

UPDATE:

So touch events are a bit of a beast. The rundown of it is this...

1. They bubble up at first from your root container in your Activity. This is done by calling `dispatchTouchEvent` and then `onInterceptTouchEvent` assuming intercepting wasn't blocked by a child view.
2. If no view intercepts the event, it will bubble to the leaf node (such as a button) where `onTouch` is called. If the node doesn't handle it (returns `true`) its parent gets a chance and so on.

This means that you can use `dispatchTouchEvent` or `onInterceptTouchEvent` to spy on touch events without changing the behavior. Unless you're actually going to intercept the event I suggest using `dispatchTouchEvent` as it's guaranteed to run whereas intercepting may be blocked (example: `DrawerLayout` will intercept touch events near the edge in order to open the drawer).

So the final result is:

```
public class MyView extends Button {
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        switch (event.getActionMasked()) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                Log.e("test", "ACTION_DOWN");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                Log.e("test", "ACTION_UP");
                break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL:
                Log.e("test", "ACTION_CANCEL");
                break;
        }
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
    }
}
```

UPDATE:

Sorry, so I've been under the impression for some reason (mostly my poor reading) that we were dealing with the parent. Here's what I would do...

Go ahead and implement `onTouch` and return `true` to consume all the events. This means that any touch events that start on your view will be eaten up. What we'll do then is translate the point to the parent's coordinate space and manually pass the touch event up, it'll look like this inside your custom view...

```
private boolean passingTouchEventToParent = true;
final private Rect hitRect = Rect();
@Override
public boolean onTouch(MotionEvent event) {
    // Handle your custom logic here

    final ViewParent viewParent = getParent();
    if (passingTouchEventToParent &&
            viewParent != null &&
            viewParent instanceof View) {
        // Gets this view's hit rectangle in the parent's space
        getHitRect(hitRect);
        event.offsetLocation((float) hitRect.left, (float) hitRect.top);
        passingTouchEventToParent = viewParent.onTouchEvent(event);
    }
    if (event.getActionMasked() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {
        // Motion event finished, reset passingTouchEventToParent
        passingTouchEventToParent = true;
    }
    return true;
}
```

Comment: can you provide an example what do you mean?

Comment: This way only `ACTION_DOWN` is detected. I have read some articles about it and as much as understand, if I don't catch `ACTION_DOWN` in my View, then it will never catch any other view afterwards.

Comment: Oh okay I was extending View, now with Button I get all the actions but this way Button always consumes all the actions. Looking into `onInterceptTouchEvent` is maybe what I need in parent viewgroup. just I need to come up with some logic to intercept only `ACTION_MOVE` and after return true so no more actions are consumed by view or viewgroup

Comment: I'll try and put something together tonight and test for you

Comment: was not exactly what I was looking for but helped me to get to right direction